# Ionic generate page - skip module file

Tags: ionic-framework

`ionic g page SomePage` also creates some-page.module.ts file. How do I prevent it from doing it?

I use Ionic 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shouldn't delete module from a page.

Page in Ionic is ment to represent the whole view, because there is also a Component which might be just a part of the view. So it is very obvious now, that every Page should have its module (for lazy loading) and a route to it.

If we generate component, we see that neither - module nor route is created, so it makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic v3, it is possible to use `--no-module`` flag, to skip the creation of module.ts file.

Try execute:

```sh
ionic g page SomePage --no-module
```

Hope this helps!